# How to get DB values into Datagridview in c# (Datagrid colums already created)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to get values from DB into Datagridview and it works fine but my problem is, I edited some Datagridview colums before get values from DB. So when I try to get values, datagridview create some new colums.

When I write these codes, the data comes in correctly, but it adds 5 new columns and adds the values ​​below it.

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds, "users");
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["users"];
```

[image]

I added only 5 columns to the datagridview.My datagridview seems like this.

[image]

When I try to get values from DB, My datagridview add 5 more colums and it seems like this

[image]

What I want is for the values ​​to be placed under the columns I created at the beginning, the other 5 columns should not be created and the values ​​should not come there.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Create a dedicated type/model for your DataGridView items and project from your DB models onto it.

Comment: Try setting the `DataPropertyName` columns to match your column names.

Comment: Additionally  to setting DataPropertyName you might also want to disable AutoGenerateColumns on the DataGridView

Comment: You really named the ID column in plural in your DB (IDs)?

Comment: could you please more specific about using DataPropertyName @LarsTech

Comment: Look at the screen image you posted.  Each one of your columns has that `DataPropertyName` property.  Match each column to the name you have in your DataTable.

Comment: ohhh!!! Thank you so much it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you synchronize the column names of the database with the DataPropertyName field, you will solve the problem.